# How to remove leading zero from date

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-format

I have a query in which i have used the following

```
date_add(DATE_FORMAT(ss.week_startdate,'%y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL (tt.day_id- 1 )DAY) as date
```

Datatype of the field is `datetime` and the result date is like this

```
2015-04-06
```

but the desired result is like this

```
2015-04-6
```

I don't need `0` in front of day. I tried this

```
date_add(DATE_FORMAT(ss.week_startdate,'%y-%m-%e'),INTERVAL (tt.day_id- 1 )DAY) as date
```

but didn't work. Can anyone help please!

Comment: Why on hold?  It is a clear question, with a simple answer.

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%c-%d');` --> `2015-4-28`

Comment: @paul white, I think i have mentioned the scenario clear with every details then why on hold? Did i miss anything?

Comment: Five people with the [cast close votes moderation privilege](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) thought this question was too basic or not relevant to most of our audience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the functions applied in *wrong order*. You need to do date arithmetic first (`date_add`, whatever) and apply the `format` last:

```
DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(ss.week_startdate, INTERVAL (tt.day_id - 1) DAY),
             '%Y-%m-%e')
```

You also need `%Y` for a 4-digit year, not `%y`.

---

Also note that it's better to also change the first query, as it does a lot of redundant operations:

```
date_add(
    DATE_FORMAT(ss.week_startdate,'%y-%m-%d'),
                INTERVAL (tt.day_id- 1 )DAY
               )
as date
```

- First, it calculates: `DATE_FORMAT(ss.week_startdate,'%y-%m-%d')`
  which converts the datetime value to a string with format (example for current date, 2015 April 28): `'15-04-28'`.
- Then, it does: `date_add( previous_result,  INTERVAL (tt.day_id-1) DAY)`
  But the `previous_result` is a string so it has to be converted to `date` or `datetime`. It's only by accident that the 2-year format does not lead to a wrong date. After this conversion, the `date_add()` is calculated and because the first argument (after the conversion) is a `date` and you only add days, not hours or smaller unit, the result is also a `date`.
- Then, the `as day` is considered but this does nothing, as the previous operation has resulted in a `date`, too.
- Finally, the result is shown in the default format for dates, which (by one more accident!) is `%Y-%m-%d`, to get the wanted format.

In all, three conversions (`datetime -> char -> date -> char`), while you only need one.